# How to rotate several strings at one time

Tags: javascript, html, string, rotation

I'm trying to make a webpage. But I have a problem with rotating strings.
I want to make several strings to rotate when the page is loaded. 
If there is only one string, it rotates well with this code.
But when there are two or more strings and I give them the same `class` to rotate with equivalent JavaScript code, it's not working.

It's working(Only the first string)

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><span id="div" style="background-color:yellowgreen">
            What to eat at Newton Food Centre</span>
            </li><p>
            <!--<li><span class="div" style="background-color:skyblue">the 
             most unique cocktails in Singapore</span></li>-->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var div = document.getElementById("div");

        var timer = setInterval("doRotate()",200);

        div.onclick = function (e) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }

        function doRotate() {
            var str = div.innerHTML;
            var firstChar = str.substr(0,1);
            var remains = str.substr(1, str.length-1);
            str = remains + firstChar;
            div.innerHTML = str;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

and this is not working

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="div" style="background-color:yellowgreen">
                What to eat at Newton Food Centre</span></li><p>
            <li><span class="div" style="background-color:skyblue">
                the most unique cocktails in Singapore</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName("div");

        var timer = setInterval("doRotate()",200);

        div.onclick = function (e) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }

        function doRotate() {
            var str = div.innerHTML;
            var firstChar = str.substr(0,1);
            var remains = str.substr(1, str.length-1);
            str = remains + firstChar;
            div.innerHTML = str;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to see those two strings are rotating at one time.
Please tell me the error that I'm making...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("div")` will return an object of many divs and not a single div so you need to iterate on them like this :

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("div");

var timer = setInterval("doRotate()", 200);

for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].onclick = function(e) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

function doRotate() {
  for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    var str = div[i].innerHTML;
    var firstChar = str.substr(0, 1);
    var remains = str.substr(1, str.length - 1);
    str = remains + firstChar;
    div[i].innerHTML = str;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="div" style="background-color:yellowgreen">
                What to eat at Newton Food Centre</span></li>
      <p>
        <li><span class="div" style="background-color:skyblue">
                the most unique cocktails in Singapore</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know that 'document.getElementsByClassName("div")' returns an array! Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an array @TemaniAfif.

Comment: @AngelPolitis yes sure, but what i meant by "array" is many items and not single item, i didn't meant array as the structure, maybe i should change the term :)

Comment: An array is also a single item except the fact that it contains other items. I think 'a collection of elements' would be a more appropriate term in this case :)